# How to assign custom claims between user types?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a project using React and Firebase.
I'm trying to assign custom claims for two different user types, buyer and seller, each with a different UI.
I have created 2 different user signup pages that will assign custom claims on the client side in javascript. I've recently learnt that assigning custom claims should be done on Cloud Functions using `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` as its unsafe on the client side.

My question is, how would I distinguish, and appropriately assign claim, between buyer and seller in cloud functions when the function is triggered by a new user?

Comment: This type of question typically boils down to: "if you'd get an email from a user, how would you determine their role/claims?" If the answer is: "I have a list of emails from users who I invited and their types" then you'd also implement this list somewhere where your Cloud Functions can find it.